# Elasticsearch - Missing Field Value For Nested Field - Function Score Query | v7.10.2

Tags: elasticsearch

I have already posted this on the ES group but I got no response and so posted it on SO. Link https://discuss.elastic.co/t/missing-field-value-for-nested-field-function-score-query-v7-10-2/291365

I have been trying for a long time now but the nested field value is always saying missing field value while calculating the score.

Mapping:

```
{
  "doctor_idx" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "_class" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "index" : false,
          "doc_values" : false
        },
        "service" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "_class" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "index" : false,
              "doc_values" : false
            },
            "serviceTypeEarliestAvailability" : {
              "type" : "nested",
              "properties" : {
                "_class" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "index" : false,
                  "doc_values" : false
                },
                "earliestAvailableDateTimeByType" : {
                  "type" : "date",
                  "format" : "date_hour_minute_second"
                },
                "serviceType" : {
                  "type" : "text"
                },
                "servicesMedium" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For simplicity, I have kept just one record. A glimpse of the record

```
"serviceTypeEarliestAvailability" : [
              {
                "serviceType" : "Service Type",
                "earliestAvailableDateTimeByType" : "2021-12-09T19:39:16",
                "servicesMedium" : [
                  "MED1",
                  "MED2",
                  "MED3",
                  "MED4"
                ]
              }
            ],
```

The following query gives: "A document doesn't have a value for a field! Use doc[].size()==0 to check if a document is missing a field!"

I tried using `field_value_factor` instead of `script_score` but it's the same problem and it complains about the missing field value.

Query 1: with script_score

```
GET /doctor_idx/_search
{
  "explain": true,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "service",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "score_mode": "max",
          "path": "service.serviceTypeEarliestAvailability",
          "query": {
            "function_score": {
              "query": {
                "match_all": {
                  "boost": 1
                }
              },
              "functions": [
                {
                  "filter": {
                    "match": {
                      "service.serviceTypeEarliestAvailability.serviceType": "type" // no complaints about this
                    }
                  },
                  "weight": 10
                },
                {
                  "script_score": {
                    "script": {
          "source":     "(doc['service.serviceTypeEarliestAvailability.earliestAvailableDateTimeByType'].value.getMillis())"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query 2 : With `field_value_factor`

```
GET /doctor_idx/_search
{
  "explain": true,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "service",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "score_mode": "max",
          "path": "service.serviceTypeEarliestAvailability",
          "query": {
            "function_score": {
              "query": {
                "match_all": {
                  "boost": 1
                }
              },
              "functions": [
                {
                  "filter": {
                    "match": {
                      "service.serviceTypeEarliestAvailability.serviceType": "type" 
                    }
                  },
                  "weight": 10
                },
                {
                  "field_value_factor": {
                    "field": "service.serviceTypeEarliestAvailability.earliestAvailableDateTimeByType"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error From ES for Query 1:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "script_exception",
        "reason" : "runtime error",
        "script_stack" : [
          "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Dates.get(ScriptDocValues.java:160)",
          "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Dates.getValue(ScriptDocValues.java:154)",
          "(doc['service.serviceTypeEarliestAvailability.earliestAvailableDateTimeByType'].value.getMillis())",
          "                                                                               ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script" : "(doc['service.serviceTypeEarliestAvailability.earliestAvailableDateTimeByType'].value.getMillis())",
        "lang" : "painless",
        "position" : {
          "offset" : 79,
          "start" : 0,
          "end" : 98
        }
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "doctor_idx",
        "node" : "mvh5k24dQPqM-d7JVeNomQ",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "script_exception",
          "reason" : "runtime error",
          "script_stack" : [
            "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Dates.get(ScriptDocValues.java:160)",
            "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Dates.getValue(ScriptDocValues.java:154)",
            "(doc['service.serviceTypeEarliestAvailability.earliestAvailableDateTimeByType'].value.getMillis())",
            "                                                                               ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script" : "(doc['service.serviceTypeEarliestAvailability.earliestAvailableDateTimeByType'].value.getMillis())",
          "lang" : "painless",
          "position" : {
            "offset" : 79,
            "start" : 0,
            "end" : 98
          },
          "caused_by" : {
            "type" : "illegal_state_exception",
            "reason" : "A document doesn't have a value for a field! Use doc[<field>].size()==0 to check if a document is missing a field!"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Error From ES for Query 2:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "exception",
        "reason" : "Missing value for field [service.serviceTypeEarliestAvailability.earliestAvailableDateTimeByType]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "all shards failed",
    "phase" : "query",
    "grouped" : true,
    "failed_shards" : [
      {
        "shard" : 0,
        "index" : "doctor_idx",
        "node" : "mvh5k24dQPqM-d7JVeNomQ",
        "reason" : {
          "type" : "exception",
          "reason" : "Missing value for field [service.serviceTypeEarliestAvailability.earliestAvailableDateTimeByType]"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

The only record I have in the ES

```
{
  "took" : 32,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "doctor_idx",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "xM20oH0Bmp1zsT0w8pQe",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "_class" : "com.insig.clinic_apps.services_server.booking.dao.DoctorSchema",
          "id" : "xM20oH0Bmp1zsT0w8pQe",
          "metadata" : {
            "doctorId" : "xhnz2lGvXxelWyVekz82c2v6Srb2",
            "fullName" : "Dave Insig Email Test",
            "credentials" : [
              "MD"
            ],
            "languagesSpoken" : [
              "EN",
              "NOT_DEFINED"
            ],
            "specialitiesServed" : [ ],
            "city" : "VAUGHAN",
            "provincesPermitted" : [ ],
            "province" : "ON",
            "country" : "CANADA"
          },
          "service" : {
            "servicesMedium" : [
              "IN_CLINIC",
              "VIDEO",
              "MESSAGING",
              "PHONE"
            ],
            "servicesTypeDuration" : [
              {
                "serviceType" : "Acne Symptoms",
                "duration" : 5,
                "servicesMedium" : [
                  "IN_CLINIC",
                  "MESSAGING",
                  "PHONE",
                  "VIDEO"
                ]
              }
            ],
            "serviceTypeEarliestAvailability" : [
              {
                "serviceType" : "Acne Symptoms",
                "earliestAvailableDateTimeByType" : "2021-12-09T19:39:16",
                "servicesMedium" : [
                  "IN_CLINIC",
                  "MESSAGING",
                  "PHONE",
                  "VIDEO"
                ]
              }
            ],
            "bufferTimeForNextAvailability" : 0
          },
          "earliestAvailableDateTime" : "2021-12-09T19:39:16",
          "patientRating" : 4.384481,
          "onTimeRating" : 3.171053
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey could you paste the actual error log, and give a full sample document ? It will help debug ^^

Comment: @Paulo have a look

Comment: For Query1 ... you have a solution proposal in the error, it seems you have some documents that do not have value for `earliestAvailableDateTimeByType `. 

For Query2, I am not sure. But I would love to have a full sample document to try on my side

Comment: I added just one document and made sure `earliestAvailableDateTimeByType` has value in it. So, it has the value but ES is giving me that error. IDK why

Comment: @Paulo I have even added the result from ES. Have a look.

Comment: Hey man, I can not trigger an error on my end it works like a charm... both queries. which version of ES / kibana are you using ?

Comment: As mentioned in the OG question, its 7.10.2 version of ES. How about you?

Comment: latest, v 7.15.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240103/discussion-between-paulo-and-gursahib-singh-sahni).

Comment: I can't use the latest, because it is not open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, wasted a lot of time here and figured that there was no problem with the queries. Elasticsearch v7.10.2 has an issue when I try to get the explanation of the query.

It works perfectly fine **without** the `explain` parameter.

See the    `at org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.FieldValueFactorFunction$1.explainScore(FieldValueFactorFunction.java:103) ~[elasticsearch-7.10.2.jar:7.10.2]`

[image]

PS: One of the comments in the OG question mentioned that the latest Elasticsearch v7.15  works fine even with `explain` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

/!\ Partial solution /!\

#### Query 1

When I was trying to execute your query I got this error:

```json
{
    "caused_by" : {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "dynamic method [org.elasticsearch.script.JodaCompatibleZonedDateTime, toEpochMilli/0] not found"
    }
}
```

So I did a slight change to your query `.toInstant().toEpochMilli()`

```
GET /so_custom_score/_search
{
  "explain": true,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "service",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "score_mode": "max",
          "path": "service.serviceTypeEarliestAvailability",
          "query": {
            "function_score": {
              "query": {
                "match_all": {
                  "boost": 1
                }
              },
              "functions": [
                {
                  "filter": {
                    "match": {
                      "service.serviceTypeEarliestAvailability.serviceType": "type"
                    }
                  },
                  "weight": 10
                },
                {
                  "script_score": {
                    "script": {
                      "source": """
                      def availability = doc['service.serviceTypeEarliestAvailability.earliestAvailableDateTimeByType'].value;
                      return availability.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
                      """
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```